# Cocos2D - Automatically set sprite movement with speed

Tags: objective-c, animation, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I was wondering how I could immediately make my sprite `CCSprite *van` move automatically from the start with controllable speed like `int *speed = 1, 2, 3+`. I looked around but all I found were not fitting my needs. Is there a simple solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a CCSpeed action:

```
CCSpeed* speed= [CCSpeed actionWithAction: yourMoveAction speed: 1.0f];
// yourMoveAction is an action like CCMoveTo for example
[sprite runAction: speed];
```

Then you can change the speed while the sprite moves with setSpeed:

```
[speed setSpeed: 2.0f];
```